# Azure API Managment NSG setup when configuring with Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-api-management

My Azure API Management and Service Fabric are in same Vnet but is 2 different subnet.

They both have the same NSG. API management need to contact Service Fabric in port 19080

```
service-fabric-backend (0.038 ms)
{
    "message": "Resolving partition",
    "resourceId": "https://dev-myservicefabric-sf.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com:19080",
    "managementEndpoint": [
        "https://dev-myservicefabric-sf.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com:19080"
    ],
    "serviceName": {},
    "partitionKey": {
        "kind": "Singleton"
    }
}
```

This is the NSG Rule I have set. But when I set this i am not able to communicate with the service fabric. What is the correct rule configuration other than putting Any (*).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The SF NSG must be configured to allow access to the default ports used by Service Fabric, not only 19080.

In your cluster configuration these values are defined like below:

`"nodeTypes": [{
    "name": "NodeType0",
    "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
    "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19001",
    "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19002"
    "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19003",
    "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
    "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19081",
    "applicationPorts": {
        "startPort": "20575",
        "endPort": "20605"
    },
    "ephemeralPorts": {
        "startPort": "20606",
        "endPort": "20861"
    },
    "isPrimary": true
}]`

In the cluster configuration tutorial, it explains they used a pre-configured NSG:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-vnet-and-windows-cluster#virtual-network-subnet-and-network-security-group

Based on your settings, you have to open ports 19000, 19080, to publish new applications and manage the cluster.
Also these ports must be accessible from source * (internet) or from your company IP, Not just API Mgmt IPs